# Error while running this query : #1093 - You can't specify target table 'items' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

I want to update handling_status_id in items table

```
UPDATE items
SET handling_status_id=2
WHERE id = (
  SELECT id 
  FROM  `items` 
  INNER JOIN cache_items_auth ON items.id = cache_items_auth.item_id
  WHERE auth_id =2
    AND creation_date >='%2018-12-09 06:01%'
    AND  `category_id` =12151
  ORDER BY creation_date ASC
  LIMIT 1
)
```

I get this error :  #1093 - You can't specify target table 'items' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Please post your table defintions.

Answer (score 0):

For an immediate fix, you may wrap the subquery to force MySQL to materialize it before doing the update:

```
UPDATE items
SET handling_status_id = 2
WHERE id = (
    SELECT id FROM
    (
        SELECT id
        FROM items
        INNER JOIN cache_items_auth
            ON items.id = cache_items_auth.item_id
        WHERE auth_id = 2 AND
              creation_date >= '2018-12-09 06:01' AND
              category_id = 12151
        ORDER BY creation_date
        LIMIT 1
    ) x
);
```

The best solution here would probably be to rewrite your update using a series of joins.  But, without seeing your table definitions, I can't venture an answer at the moment.